# Como cargar el contenido de un div hasta el termino de obtención de datos de un ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

*Tengo un div en el cual adentro de el tengo un otro div que tiene un ng-repeat y quisiera hacer que al se cargara el contenido(nivel de vista) hasta que termine de recorrer toda la data obtenida, es que aveces se da que aparece esto {{item.nomb_prop}} o aveces no se carga las imagenes de un slider y siento que no es muy cómodo para el usuario ver eso*

## El script seria el siguiente:

```
<div class="aqui se cargaria todo"></div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('todo', function($scope, $http){
        //$scope.load = true;
        $scope.importar = function(){
            $scope.type = 'all';
            $http.post('../View/listPropiedades.php', {txtType : $scope.type}).then(sucess, error);
            function sucess(response){
                $scope.propiedades = response.data;
                if($scope.propiedades.length > 0)
                    $scope.ocultar = false;
                else 
                    $scope.ocultar = true;
            }
            function error(bad){
                $scope.propiedades = 'ERROR';
            }
            $scope.load = false;
        }
        $scope.importar();
    });
</script>
```

*Agradecería cualquier respuesta*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que eso no se vea al usuario, utiliza `ng-cloak`

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-cloak.asp

Tambien puedes hacer el binding con `ng-bind` y no se verá